# Create a new hard drive for wdmycloud on larger disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, dd

I am trying to follow the instruction wich can be found [here](https://wd.hides.su/fox_exe/WDMyCloud-Gen1/) I have followed all the instruction in the file "Replace HDD - English.txt" I have a new hard drive with 6therabyte my old hard drive has only 3 therabytes I would like to transfert the os on to the new drive without files. Howver when I compare the two drives as you cn see in my image they are not identical. [image: Linux terminal with two drives]

My question is is there a way that I can copy the partition sda1 to sdb1 and sda2 to sdb2 and sda3 to sdb3 so that they would be identical.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using a HDD duplicator?

Comment: Yes but I am unsure wich one also i do not want to duplicated every part since there is a very large part that i would preffer to transfert with internet is there a linux duplicator that would work on my wd mycloud gen 1 server?

Comment: A HDD duplicator is a device that duplicates everything on the disk.  Sounds like you want to duplicate specific partitions which will be harder, something like `dd` on the proper sectors, should acomplush your goal.

Comment: Yes @Ramhound that is what I want to do since my new hard drive is larger then the other hard drive. What command would I have to write with dd to acomplish my goal. Thank you